# Custom iPad app deployment?

Tags: iphone, ipad, sdk

I am developing custom iPad applications for clients. So far I know that you cannot distribute the same app to more than 100 iOS devices. Although I have read that this method of deploying applications is meant for "beta testing" and that I have to renew the profile every three months.

I was wondering, is there a workaround to this issue? I simply cannot be updating deployment profiles to every one of my clients I'm deploying a custom app to.

Can someone provide me with some information/advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enterprise deployment may solve this problem for you, but to the best of my knowledge Apple will not approve you until you have a large number of employees (500+).

The three month expiration of profiles is only for development profiles. If you produce an Ad Hoc build, these profiles are good for one year.

**Update August 2011:** Apple now allows iOS developers to write custom apps for businesses. Your customer needs to enroll in the Volume Purchase Program, but presumably after that you can make apps available only to them and not to the general public through the App Store. (Disclaimer: I have not yet done this myself.)

More information on Apple's page about the [Volume Purchase Program](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/volume/).

Comment: This is pretty bad, damn why does Apple want so much control over things... this is crazy. One year won't do me any good, it appears as if they encourage the jailbreaks...sigh

Comment: Manuel, you probably saw the news about this, but in case you did not, I updated my answer with a pointer to Apple's Volume Purchase Program. I bet that's exactly what you were thinking of when you posted your question.

Answer (score 3):

Your options are somewhat limited for a custom app. These are really the best options you have for your clients. With proper security and authentication the app store could a decent solution.

1. Deploy App to the app store
2. [Deploy an enterprise application](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) (Recommended, Requires Dun & Bradstreet Number)
3. Require that the app is for use on jailbroken devices

Comment: Crazy how limited the options are... At this point they are sort of forcing me to deploy my apps on jailbroken devices, where I do not have to worry about licensing or silly deployment options...

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of developer program that you can be enrolled on. For this you would need the [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)